# Problems with gmapping and Husky A200

Tags: navigation, husky, gmapping-demo, gmapping, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to build a 2D map by using Husky A200, IMU and a SICK laser with ROS Indigo.
The IMU sensor is places at the center of the robot while the SICK laser is placed 40 centimeters over the IMU sensor.

I moved the robot indoor for few meters and I recorded a bag file which contains different topics like:

```
/tf
/scan
/imu/data
/odometry/filtered
...
```

This is the bag file: [download bag 15MB](http://www.dronyx.com/bags/test1.bag).

Then, I use these commands in order to try to build the map:

```
roscore
rosparam set use_sim_time true
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch 
roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan
rosbag play --clock test1.bag
```

When I run RVIZ, I get some errors and I can't build the map.
I set /map as fixed frame.
The errors are:

```
For frame [base_laser]: No transform to fixed frame [map]
frame [laser] does not exist
```

Should I use /odom as fixed frame?

I think the problem is that I don't have a tf for the laser, but I don't understand how to solve this problem.
Can you help me, please?

**EDIT**:
I already tried to use the husky gmapping demo instead of **rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan**, but I have the same problem.
This is the content of the gmapping.launch file used by Husky in the navigation tutorial.
Do you think the problem is in this code line:

`<remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>`  at the bottom of the file ?

```
<launch>

  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan" />

  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping">
    <rosparam>
      odom_frame: odom
      base_frame: base_link
      map_frame: map

      map_update_interval: 0.5 # Publish new map

      maxUrange: 5.5 # Should be just less than sensor range
      maxRange: 6.1 # Should be just greater than sensor range
      particles: 100 # Increased from 80

      # Update frequencies
      linearUpdate: 0.3
      angularUpdate: 0.5
      temporalUpdate: 2.0
      resampleThreshold: 0.5

      # Initial Map Size
      xmin: -100.0
      ymin: -100.0
      xmax: 100.0
      ymax: 100.0
      delta: 0.05

      # All default
      sigma: 0.05
      kernelSize: 1
      lstep: 0.05
      astep: 0.05
      iterations: 5
      lsigma: 0.075
      ogain: 3.0
      lskip: 0
      llsamplerange: 0.01
      llsamplestep: 0.01
      lasamplerange: 0.005
      lasamplestep: 0.005

    </rosparam>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242186/problems-with-gmapping-and-husky-a200/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-08-23**:
I have downloaded and played your bag. I realized that your /scan topic has frame id as "laser" but your tf tree has no transform from "base_link" to "laser". The error msg you saw makes sense too. You might have missed out this transform or made some mistake with the setting up of scan topic

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-08-23**:
For the scan topic, I only run my SICK with **rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node _host:=192.168.1.10** without doing anything else. Can you suggest me how to create the transformation for the scan, please? I tried: **rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 1 0 0 0 base_link laser 100** with no result.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-08-23**:
Any tip to solve this problem?

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-08-23**:
It is a good direction to try static transform. Did you run this static transform during recording or playback? I think it s best if you do when recording. Please do so and upload the new bag. I will try to run gmapping with it

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-08-24**:
I run this tf: **rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.3 0 0.4 0 0 0 base_link laser 100** while recording a new [bag file](http://www.dronyx.com/bags/sick_lms.bag). What do you think about it? Now I can see the laser in my tf tree, but it isn't working anyway.. :(

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-08-24**:
I have played your latest bag. I was able to see the map from gmapping. I used both methods (rosrun and your launch file), both are showing the map on rviz. No error is shown in the rosout of gmapping. Maybe you can try to remove and reinstall gmapping? (Im using ros indigo by the way)

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-08-24**:
Yes, now I'm able to build the 2D map correctly! Just a question: why I'm not able to set a navigation goal and make the robot navigate towards it inside the built map? What I have to do if I want to achieve this result? Gmapping can't do this?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-08-24**:
This bug was fixed a while ago but never bloomed [here](https://github.com/husky/husky_robot/commit/c29110cada09474b3ef1cb56fca464e4d9a85178).  As for the nav goal, are just running gmapping or the gmpapping demo?  `move_base` is used to move the robot.

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-08-25**:
@marcus-barnet: So how did you get the mapping working? Please post as "Answer". As for navigation, do you mean navigate in the built map? If so, please post a separate question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to make it work by following the suggestions given by DavidN.

```
roscore
rosparam set use_sim_time true
roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
roslaunch husky_navigation gmapping_demo.launch 
rosbag play --clock file.bag
```

The bag file should also include the transformation the `base_link` and the `laser sensor`.
The last command also launches `move_base`.
I'm able to build the map, but I can't set a navigation goal inside it.

Anyway, the topic was about map building, so I will have to open another question.

---

Originally posted by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) with karma: 287 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0